# Is there any way to Schedule a Cron Programatically

Tags: magento2, cron, magento-cron

I have created a CRON from My Customer this extension has a CRON. now the client is asking me to do something that CRON should schedule automatically on Magento Extension Installation

He doesn't want to run `php bin/magento cron:run`

Comment: I donot think you need to run `php bin/magento cron:run` if ,corn is already install at your server https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#create-the-magento-crontab

Comment: then you do not need to  your cron sperated